# How to overlay message compose window

Tags: xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I want to overlay all window compose message from thunderbird to a new xul window. I've tried

```
   <?xul-overlay href="chrome://messenger/content/messenger.xul"?>
   <?xul-overlay href="chrome://messenger/content/messengercompose/messengercompose.xul"?>
```

but this not overlay message textarea and other tools,

[image]

i need all tools and menu from message compose window to be overlayed
[image]

please, any help will be very appreciate

Answer (score 1):

The information that you have provided is a bit sparse. You have listed the following as one group of code:

```
<?xul-overlay href="chrome://messenger/content/messenger.xul"?>
<?xul-overlay href="chrome://messenger/content/messengercompose/messengercompose.xul"?>
```

From this, it is not clear if you are attempting to overlay two separate `.xul` files from within the same overlay file.

Overlays are specified with a one-to-one correspondence between the file being overlayed and the overlay file.  In other words, to overlay those two files, you need two separate files to have two overlays (or perhaps you could overlay the same information from one file onto two).

[Overlays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Overlays) are defined in the [chrome.manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration) file. Use a single line per file you are overlaying.  The syntax looks like:

```
overlay chrome://URI-to-be-overlaid chrome://overlay-URI [flags]
```

The [[Flags] are described on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#Manifest_Flags).